# How to respect single responsability principle in this situation using java?

Tags: java, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

Let's assume I have three channels (they are just a concept not a class): `A`, `B`, `C`.

Every channel has some objects that I want to process and that are different between them. Let's supose :

- Channel `A` has `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.
- Channel `B` has `B1`, `B2` and `B3`.
- Channel `C` has `C1`, `C2` and `C3`.

All channels have a common `save` method that stores those objects.

My approach was to have an interface `ATaskProcessor` with all channels methods:

- `a1Process(arguments)`  `a2Process(arguments)`  `a3Process(arguments)`
- `b1Process(arguments)`  `b2Process(arguments)`  `b3Process(arguments)`
- `c1Process(arguments)`  `c2Process(arguments)`  `c3Process(arguments)`

And then an implementation of that interface with all those methods implemented and a common `save` in order to store the obects processed. I need a different process for every single object but I use the same `save`.

The goal of that approach was to reuse the same `save` method to all objects, but that does not respect **single responsibility principle** and is not scalable.

I thought about separating the channels in diferent packages which will reduce my class code, but I will have repeated code and I won't respect the principle neither.

How could I do to respect **single responsibility principle** and repeat the less code possible?

Example:

```
public interface ATaskProcessor {

  void a1Process(arguments);
  void a2Process(arguments);
  void a3Process(arguments);

  void b1Process(arguments);
  void b2Process(arguments);
  void b3Process(arguments);

  void c1Process(arguments);
  void c2Process(arguments);
  void c3Process(arguments);

}

public class taskProcessor implements ATaskProcessor {

  void a1Process(arguments){ ... }
  void a2Process(arguments){ ... }
  void a3Process(arguments){ ... }

  void b1Process(arguments){ ... }
  void b2Process(arguments){ ... }
  void b3Process(arguments){ ... }

  void c1Process(arguments){ ... }
  void c2Process(arguments){ ... }
  void c3Process(arguments){ ... }

  void save() { ... }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what those channels are and what those tasks are? Currently the only thing we can say for sure is that your proposed design looks very clumsy, and there's definitely better ways to do what you want, as long as we understand what you want.

Comment: I wanted to generify it, but okay I will explain the exact situation. The channels are google, bing and amazon for example. And I have the following objects: account, campaign and metrics. So I actually download information from those channels and process them in order to save it in database. That being said, I have an accountProcessor, campaignProcessor and metricsProcessor for every channel (I cannot unify them, because they need different process). It helps @Kayaman?

Comment: Yes, it paints a lot clearer picture. Would it be possible to offload some of the behaviour to the Task objects themselves instead of making the TaskProcessor try to do so many things? I'd also try to make the TaskProcessor channel specific, since while all channels might be very similar, they still have their own distinct source.

Comment: So you mean I should create a GoogleTaskProcessor, BingTaskProcessor and AmazonTaskProcessor (each one  with the 3 methods: account, campaign and metrics processor)? The objects only have attributes which I have to process, but nothing else. All the logic is in the taskProcessor and I think it should be like that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can have them share a superclass if there's behaviour that can be shared, but there's no reason to try to force Bing and Google to the same exact mold. The interface can probably be generic like in Tobb's example, and if you want to lazily find a processor you could implement something like `boolean isApplicable(Task)` method which will return true if that processor can process that task (this also allows you to create a processor that can process all the tasks for logging or other such purpose).

Comment: Okay, I will proceed that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This really does depend a bit on the relationship between A, B, and C, as well as 1, 2, and 3 (is A1 and B1 somewhat of the same thing?)

But if I make a few assumptions, one way of solving this is through inheritance and generics:

```
public abstract class Task { }
public class A extends Task { }
public class B extends Task { }
public class C extends Task { }

public <T extends Task> interface TaskProcessor<T> {
    process1(T task);
    process2(T task);
    process3(T task);
}

public class AProcessor implements TaskProcessor<A> {
    //...
}

public class BProcessor implements TaskProcessor<B> {
    //...
}

public class CProcessor implements TaskProcessor<C> {
    //...
}
```

Then if you want to introduce another task type, D, all you need is:

```
public class D extends Task {}
public class DProcessor implements TaskProcessor<D> {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I think I did not explain properly my situation. All the objects are different and a channel does not make sense as entity, it's just a concept. I added an example in order to make it more visual, hope it helps.